# "Making tag completion table" Freezes/Blocks -- how to disable

Tags: completion, performance, ctags

**TLDR: I've got a large tags file that loads multiple times per session, making it unusable.  Can't find the source of issue or how to disable it -- main goal is to jump to tags, but completion would be nice**

I recently posted on the emacs subreddit and a user recommended that I join this group because it's also friendly towards newbies.

I've been using emacs as a C++ IDE, and I'm slowly correcting things that are annoying.  I'm essentially using [redguardtoo's emacs.d file](https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d).

I have a tag file that is 225MB (1.6M Tags).  My intent for the tag is not necessarily completion (using `company`), but more for jumping around source code.  I'm working with an unfamiliar code base and often need to see macro or class definitions.

When I start typing, at random times, I'll see a message in the minibuffer

```
Making tag completion table for [tag file]...0-100%
```

Then, a popup listbox shows up with autocompletion options.

Because this tag file is so large, and it doesn't seem like the tag loading is asynchronous, it freezes emacs for around a minute.  This also happens multiple times per a session (with the same file, and with other files in the same directory that use the same tag file)!

---

**Questions**

1. Does anyone know what's initializing the loading of the tag table for completion and how to disable it?  I did a grep on my emacs.d directory for "Making tag completion" and found nothing (note, IIRC the loading tags was present regardless of using `company` or `auto-complete`
2. Completion would be nice, but I'd settle just for the ability to jump to the tag location.  Is there a way to get this?
3. What is the mindset to take when approaching problems like this?  I'd like to be able to troubleshoot further on my own next time.

---

**Additional info**

Enabled minor modes (C-h m)

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Column-Number Company Desktop-Save
Display-Time Electric-Indent Electric-Pair Evil Evil-Local
Evil-Matchit Evil-Surround Fic File-Name-Shadow Flyspell-Lazy
Font-Lock Ggtags Global-Auto-Revert Global-Company Global-Eldoc
Global-Evil-Matchit Global-Evil-Surround Global-Font-Lock Global-Linum
Global-Page-Break-Lines Global-Pointback Global-Undo-Tree Helm
Helm-Match-Plugin Helm-Occur-Match-Plugin Line-Number Linum Menu-Bar
Mouse-Wheel Override-Global Pointback Recentf Savehist Shell-Dirtrack
Subword Tooltip Undo-Tree Which-Function Window-Numbering Winner Yas
Yas-Global
```

`package-activated-list` is equal to

```
(ace-jump-mode ag s dash anaconda-mode f dash s dash json-rpc auto-compile packed bbdb bookmark+ browse-kill-ring buffer-move clean-aindent-mode cmake-mode coffee-mode color-theme company cpputils-cmake crontab-mode csharp-mode diminish dired+ dired-details dropdown-list dsvn elnode kv db kv fakir kv dash noflet creole kv noflet s noflet dash web s dash emmet-mode erlang evil-args evil goto-chg undo-tree evil-search-highlight-persist exec-path-from-shell expand-region f dash s fakir kv dash noflet fancy-narrow flymake-coffee flymake-easy flymake-css flymake-easy flymake-haml flymake-easy flymake-jslint flymake-easy flymake-lua flymake-python-pyflakes flymake-easy flymake-ruby flymake-easy flymake-sass flymake-easy flymake-shell flymake-easy flyspell-lazy fringe-helper ggtags git-gutter git-timemachine gitconfig-mode gitignore-mode goto-chg haskell-mode helm-descbinds helm async helm-gtags helm async hl-sexp htmlize ibuffer-vc idomenu iedit json-mode json-snatcher json-reformat json-reformat json-rpc json-snatcher kv legalese less-css-mode lua-mode magit git-rebase-mode git-commit-mode markdown-mode maxframe mic-paren move-text multi-term mwe-log-commands noflet org-fstree packed page-break-lines paredit pointback pomodoro pretty-mode project-local-variables quack rainbow-delimiters regex-tool rinari jump inflections findr ruby-compilation inf-ruby inf-ruby robe inf-ruby ruby-compilation inf-ruby rvm sass-mode haml-mode scratch scss-mode session sr-speedbar string-edit dash switch-window tagedit dash s textile-mode undo-tree unfill w3m web s dash wgrep ws-butler yaml-mode yasnippet
```

Comment: For jumping to definition/references, you can use GNU Global with ggtags/helm-gtags. Guarantee to work on large project like Linux kernel without any delay. You may want to look at my [C/C++ guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html). I covered code navigation (jump to definition/references), code completion, compiling and debugging support. I already created a demo configuration for playing with, so you only need to walk through the features without configuring anything.

Comment: Your guides were the ones that got me started with emacs (especially w/ C++)! Our build system is very complicated and `#include "..."` can live in various places that are not known until build time.  So, ggtags wouldn't be able to generate tags for many of the files.  Currently, our build tools allow us to `make etags` to generate emacs compatible tags, but there is no `make ggtags` equivalent.  So, I'm stuck with etags for now.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm I see. The situation is more complicated now. You mentioned `ggtags` cannot generate tags, but did you use plain `gtags` on the command line at project root? You should try this and invoke ggtags again. There should not be `make ggtags` because the real command is `gtags`; `ggtags` is just a package name of Emacs that use it. Another option is that you can use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/); `ggtags` can also recognize `ctags` tags and it's also fast. You can generate ctags tags when invoking `ggtags-create-tags` and it asks for using `ctags` client.

Comment: Anyway, if `gtags` could not know about such details, I don't think the built-in `etags` (comes with Emacs), or `ctags` (I linked above) would be able to do it. I think you only use `ggtags` to create tags at current directory, not project root. Run the command `gtags` at project root, or when `ggtags` asks for where to generate, navigate to project root and you will be fine.

Comment: I verified your statement (all the tag programs can only generate from project root down the tree).  `make etags` works because it calls etags once it evaluates where all the `.h` files live.

Comment: So, it did work? If so, may I turn my comment into answer?

Comment: So, if I'm stuck with etags for completeness, do you have any suggestions for 1) Loading the tag file asynchronously 2) Disable autoreload of the tags file?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear.  Without involving the `make` command, any tag generation is incomplete.  You can turn your comment into an answer, and I can accept it in a day or two to give others a chance to answer

Comment: There's one possibility, not sure if you try: since you already have you TAGS file at project root (generated by `etags`), `ggtags` will use that file instead of GTAGS. Did you move the TAGS file (generated by `etags`) elsewhere? Personally, I use `helm-gtags` + GTAGS and always jump instantly, even in the Linux kernel that `etags` generates almost 1 GB. You mention that only some ".h" files available at build time, do you mean those files only generated after the build? Even if it is the case, it's hard to think that any tag program misses those if search recursively.

Comment: Thanks! I saw your post on helm gtags and this'll work for me for now!  Please create an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I added auto-completion to the answer. Please check it out. It could solve your completion problem, since thousands of candidates are no problem with Helm.

Comment: @cheezy What Emacs version are you using? Without touch the `TAGS` file, I was unable to make Emacs say "Making tag completion table ..." even twice. And when I changed that file (removed, actually), I've been prompted whether I wanted to re-read it. So you might want to check your value of `tags-revert-without-query`.

Comment: And if you can provide a stable step-by-step scenario where a non-modified `TAGS` file gets repeatedly re-parsed by Emacs, that should be a good material for a bug report. Do you maybe use some package that kills buffers that haven't been switched to for some time? Because a tags table is kept in a buffer.

Comment: @Dmitry, I may have some time tomorrow to check this.  I'm using emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32). I was not aware that TAGs stay in the buffer, so it is very possible that a package that is installed is killing the buffer.  I've updated my post with the variable `package-activated-list` if you're curious

Comment: @Dmitry additionally, your comment made me realize something. I'll check into it, but it's a possibility that something inside redguardtoo's emacs file that updates tags during a save, which could explain the (previously) random behavior

Comment: @cheezy You really should test it in a bare Emacs session with an empty configuration. Maybe even without installing company: open one of the files, type `M-x visit-tags-table`, enter the path to `TAGS`, and then type `C-M-i` to complete using that table. `company-etags` reuses a lot of the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case, there's still hope though. Since you use `etags`, it can be used with `helm-etags-select`, the Helm built-in command. To use it, simply follow theses steps:

- First, run the command to generate TAGS file.
- Second, use `find-tag` to feed it to Emacs; if the TAGS file is too large and Emacs asks you to confirm, just accept it. Your whole TAGS file will be loaded in Emacs and there's no more reloading.
- Finally, just execute `helm-etags-select` on any symbol on your Emacs. If there exists only one definition in your project, jump instantly; otherwise, display a  Helm buffer for you to choose from.

For completion, since you have a large tag database, you would not want to use `auto-complete` or `company` popup because it would freeze your Emacs. In that case, you can use [helm-company](https://github.com/yasuyk/helm-company); it replaces `company` popup with Helm buffer. You can simply add it to your `c-mode-hook` or `c++-mode-hook`:

```
(defun helm-company-setup ()
   (local-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'helm-company)
   (local-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-company))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'helm-company-setup)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'helm-company-setup)
```

Comment: it worked well! using helm and disabling the tags backend for company significantly improved performance. Your guide on helm switched me over from ido btw!

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Comment: @TuDo Why would the popup freeze Emacs? What happens if you first `find-tag` and then try to use `company`?

Comment: @Dmitry well when you have thousands of candidates need listing, then it blocks Emacs.

Comment: @TuDo That's not a good explanation. While fetching so many candidates may take some time, displaying them (and navigating the list, searching, etc) is very snappy even with 8000 items. I just don't have a project/backend combination that would return more, to test.

Comment: Update: 30000 is also snappy, the only perceptible delay happens before the popup opens.

Comment: @Dmitry you can test it with company-gtags in the Linux kernel. Run `copmany-gtags` and wait it blocks for a while. Run `helm-company`, it appears *instantly*.

Comment: @Dmitry well you are right. The delay only happened when retrieving tags, and for a large database, it took so long. Did the popup work fine displaying all 30000 candidates?

Comment: @Dmitry I tried it again. Although the popup did display all the completion, but after I scrolled down a bit it started lagging and finally Emacs was hanged.

Comment: @TuDo I can't reproduce the hanging. Would you like to file a proper issue?

Comment: @TuDo Although I tried `company-etags`, not `company-gtags`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Dmitry I can't say for certain if this is the cause of company or auto-complete (I'm fairly certain it happened with either).  Whatever the backend is that loads the etags is what blocks, taking around 2-3min to reload

Comment: @cheezy Here's we're discussing the performance of `company-gtags`, actually, and it has different tradeoffs than `company-etags`. Check out the recent issue at the company tracker.