# Class inheritance tree in ECB

Tags: c++, semantic-mode, ctags

I'd like to see the inheritance tree for classes which I have currently open, similarly to how it ECB shows related files (e.g. I have a class B in my buffer, its parent A and child C are in different files - show me a tree with classes A, B, C).

I tried ebrowse and it sort of works, but I'd like to see only the relevant part of it and in a more user-friendly format. I'm using semantic and I'd guess that it should be able to figure out the hierarchy from its database, but I cannot find anything about it.

I found [semantic-cb-speedbar-mode](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/contrib/xemacs/share/2005-12-08/xemacs-packages/lisp/semantic/semantic-cb.el) in a file `semantic-cb.el` in XEmacs,  which sounds like what I want, but my distribution of Emacs doesn't have it (I'm using GNU Emacs 24.4).

Similar question: [Class Browsing in C++](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3119/8412)